# Edit HTML and put data stored in $password and then use it without writing it

Tags: html, powershell

I find and create template in HTML file and I would like to convert variable.

Example:

```
$test = 'francker'
(Get-Content C:\temp\passsword2.html).Replace('$password', '$test') |
    Out-File C:\check.html
```

If I put `$password` inside of the file, the script will put `$test` but I want "francker" because I will save in another file and then send by email.

I want to do this because I would like to send a new password by email.

My template is ready and email function too. I know how to copy file in another place.

Other information I have created GUI with windows form.

Thank you Ansgar Wiechers .I put quote '$password'  it's for that does not work .

Also I discover one interesting thing's .
I can change some data inside on this file and then use it without writing it .

That's perfect because .

Comment: `'$test'` -> `$test`. The single quotes prevent PowerShell from expanding the variable.

Comment: Thank you so much ,I haven't try without quote .
It was simple .

do you know how to edit without write file ?

Comment: You can't modify a file without writing it.

Comment: ok
Thank you for everything .

Comment: I find a solution to edit file whithout writing it

I think powershell load file in variable and then edit .I am NOT sur about this .

I am sur about one thing that perflectly fine without writing it and then I can use it .

I Have something like that 
$message.body = $body 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver) 
$smtp.Send($message) 
$body=(Get-Content C:\temp\test4.htm) | foreach {$_.replace('$password',$test)} | foreach {$_.replace('$user',$user)} | foreach {$_.replace('$manager',$manager)}

Comment: That still changes only the variable `$body` in memory - not a file on disk. You can also use the `.replace() ` method one after the other. No need to insert a foreach inbetween. same applies for the `-replace` operator. `$body=(Get-Content C:\temp\test4.htm).replace('\`$password',$test).replace('\`$user',$user).replace('\`$manager',$manager)` But **please [edit]** your question to contain additional information.

Comment: ok ,I am sorry .I want to write clear text but I don't the command on this forum .
How can you back to the line ,because does not work for me when I push
SHIFT+Enter .When I write I can see back to the line after this things disappear .

Comment: I have no idea how to parse that. Please try Google Translate.